# uwsgi uwsgi flask app and nginx gives 404 not found

Tags: nginx, flask, uwsgi

I got stuck. I want to deploy python dash app on my vps. I started with flask app following this tutorial:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-uswgi-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-18-04

So I created service myproject. Checking status seems to be ok:
[image: log]

My nginx configuration:

```
server {

    listen       443 ssl http2;
    #listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name  www.mysite.com mysite.com;
    root         /var/www/wordpress;
    index        index.php;

    access_log   /var/log/nginx/wordpress.log;
    error_log    /var/log/nginx/wordpress_error.log  error;

    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/www.XXX.key;
    ssl_certificate     /etc/nginx/ssl/www.XXX.pem;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
    ssl_ciphers ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers off;

    add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=31536000;


    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
        }


    location /shiny/ {
       rewrite ^/shiny/(.*)$ /$1 break;
       proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3838;
       proxy_redirect http://127.0.0.1:3838 $scheme://$host/shiny/;
       proxy_http_version 1.1;
       proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
       proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;

       proxy_temp_file_write_size 64k;
       proxy_connect_timeout 10080s;
       proxy_send_timeout 10080;
       proxy_read_timeout 10080;
       proxy_buffer_size 64k;
       proxy_buffers 16 32k;
       proxy_busy_buffers_size 64k;
       proxy_redirect off;
       proxy_request_buffering off;
       proxy_buffering off;
    }
    location /rstudio/ {

       rewrite ^/rstudio/(.*)$ /$1 break;
       proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8787;
       proxy_redirect http://127.0.0.1:8787 $scheme://$host/rstudio/;
       #proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
       #proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
       #proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
       proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
       proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
       proxy_http_version 1.1;
       #proxy_redirect off;
       proxy_buffering off;
       #proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
       #proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
       proxy_read_timeout 86400;
    }


   location /myproject/ {
        uwsgi_pass unix:/home/XXX/XXX/python_dash/myproject/myproject.sock;
        include uwsgi_params;
        }

}
```

But when i go to mysite.com/myproject/ I get:
[image]

However it's diffrent than regular nginx (appearing in response to misspelling):

[image]

So something is going on. Its also visible on myproject service status. Every time when I try to access it it shows a line at the bottom:

```
[pid: 1696|app: 0|req: 1/1] 213.134.X.XX () {58 vars in 1334 bytes} [Fri Dec  3 13:22:08 2021] GET /myproject/ => generated 232 bytes in 40 msecs (HTTP/2.0 404) 2 headers in 87 bytes (2 switches on core 0)
```

my myproject.ini:

```
[uwsgi]
module = wsgi:app

master = true
processes = 5

socket = myproject.sock
chmod-socket = 666
vacuum = true

die-on-term = true
```

Can you give me a hint? I got stuck on that and cant solve it...

Best regards
Tomasz

Comment: I suspect it's your flask app returning a 404, can you try to run:
`curl -vL --no-buffer -XGET --unix-socket /home/XXX/XXX/python_dash/myproject/myproject.sock http://localhost/myproject/`

Comment: Taek, here is the response:

Note: Unnecessary use of -X or --request, GET is already inferred.
*   Trying /home/lemur/Knight_Frank/python_dash/myprojec:0...
* Connected to localhost (myproject.sock) port 80 (#0)
> GET /myproject/ HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost
> User-Agent: curl/7.68.0
> Accept: */*
>
* Empty reply from server
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
curl: (52) Empty reply from server

Comment: @Taek , any ideas how to proceede?

Comment: No clue, sorry. Maybe try debugging by using proxy_pass over http instead of a socket.

Answer (score 1):

Finally found it!

@app.route must match with location in nginx config

so in my case when:

```
location /myproject/
```

app route must be:

```
@app.route("/myproject/")
```

Remember about trailing "/" because if you don't add it it will return not found if you type trailing "/" in address bar (like https://website.com/myproject/ will not work, only https://website.com/myproject)

Similar thing is with python dash, but this time @app.route (or @server.route) doesn't work. You need to add routes_pathname_prefix="/myproject/" in dash.Dash(...).

I don't understand why it works that way, but it works.